# Cannot identify how to query SQL data in unusual format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been practicing data manipulation in SQL Server Express 2017, and I have been provided with a data source I can't seem to make sense of. I was hoping there might be someone more familiar here that might be able to point me in the right direction. I need to work on some SQL queries on the dataset, but I haven't the faintest idea on where to start.

The data looks like this for instance:

```
Company Code - Field - Value (3 fields)

1001 - Vendor Name - 7 Eleven

1001 - Vendor Name - Bob Jane 

1001 - Vendor Name - Krispy Kreme

1001 - Vendor Address - 102 Reservoir Street

1001 - Vendor Address - 110 Pitt Road

1001 - Vendor Address - 23 Foxy Place
```

Usually, I would expect to see it in a somewhat relational type of table like

```
Company Code Vendor Name Vendor Address

1001 7 Eleven 102 Reservoir Street. 

1001 Bob Jane 110 Pitt Road.
```

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: and it is virtually impossible to answer without knowing what database you are using "sql" is not enough detail because syntax differs for each database

Comment: What is your question here exactly? Looks like you have rows of data for the different properties of an individual. I can't, however, see any link between the rows to specify which individual it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

What you have appears to be a design called EAV - entity attribute value. That term you can google. Unfortunately either you left out important information or your design is fundamentally broken. Given what you posted, there is no way to know that "Bob Jane" goes with "110 Pitt Road". Rows in a table have no reliable or specific order. You need a column in your table to define "order" if you want to associate rows based on "order".